# ListView vs ScrollView and MeasureText in page in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]

I have a page i need to design in Xamarin.Forms.

Its a dynamic list that have several levels and it changes according to the items i am choosing.

The list can be large - up to 10K items

1. should i use a listview with CellView that changes for each line ?
   for example the first line will be a label "scout" and the next line will be values, 
   OR
   should i use scrollView with stacklayout containing stacklayouts for each line ? 
   OR
   TableView ?
   which has better performance.
2. How can i measure the width of the text so i can create each box like "sector 1" according to this width ?